# How to calculate sum of multiplied rows in Excel

Tags: excel, checksum

Please kindly help me to examine this sheet:

[image]

My current formula at cell C3 is `C3=D3*F3+E3*G3+H3*J3+I3*K3` I would like to know if there is any better formula because the real sheet has around 30 projects.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you able to organize the Project, Time J, Time S into one per row?  So that on row 3, you would have Project A, Time J, Time S, then on row 4, you would have Project B, Time J, Time S, etc.?

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot restructure the sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your 30 projects span from D3:DS3, try this formula:

```
=SUM($D$3:$DS$3*(MOD(COLUMN($D$3:$DS$3),4)=0)*$F$3:$DU$3*(MOD(COLUMN($F$3:$DU$3),4)=2))+
SUM($E$3:$DT$3*(MOD(COLUMN($E$3:$DT$3),4)=1)*$G$3:$DV$3*(MOD(COLUMN($G$3:$DV$3),4)=3))
```

You need to enter it as array formula, i.e. instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>!

Comment: I tried Ctrl Shift Enter trick but somehow it did not work. A message shows to suggest us replace ",4" as ";4". When I replace those, #VALUE! appears. Is that because of the difference between value format of cells (number and hour). Thanks!

Comment: yes, you need to replace `,`with `;` as this is your local setting. But then you still need to press Ctrl-Shift-Enter, else you'll get the #VALUE error!

Comment: Yes, finally I did it! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use sumproduct formula to complete this task if you are using excel 2007 or above.

Comment: Is there any way to shorten the formula? = SUM(SUMPRODUCT(F4:G4;H4:I4);SUMPRODUCT(J4:K4;L4:M4);SUMPRODUCT(N4:O4;P4:Q4);SUMPRODUCT(R4:S4;T4:U4);SUMPRODUCT(V4:W4;X4:Y4);SUMPRODUCT(Z4:AA4;AB4:AC4);SUMPRODUCT(AD4:AE4;AF4:AG4);SUMPRODUCT(AH4:AI4;AJ4:AK4);SUMPRODUCT(AL4:AM4;AN4:AO4);SUMPRODUCT(AP4:AQ4;AR4:AS4);SUMPRODUCT(AT4:AU4;AV4:AW4);SUMPRODUCT(AX4:AY4;AZ4:BA4);SUMPRODUCT(BB4:BC4;BD4:BE4);SUMPRODUCT(BF4:BG4;BH4:BI4);SUMPRODUCT(BJ4:BK4;BL4:BM4);SUMPRODUCT(BN4:BO4;BP4:BQ4);SUMPRODUCT(BR4:BS4;BT4:BU4);SUMPRODUCT(BV4:BW4;BX4:BY4);SUMPRODUCT(BZ4:CA4;CB4:CC4);SUMPRODUCT(CD4:CE4;CF4:CG4))

Answer (score 0):

Just put in the first cell address and last cell address, using the product expression

```
C3 = PRODUCT(D3:K3)
```

Comment: I believe this solution is the answer to OP's question

Comment: this won't work - see pattern of the multiplications requested! Too complicated for a simple `PRODUCT` formula!

Comment: Can you guys please review my current formula? @Peter: Thanks for editing my question. I don't have enough "reputation" to post image ;-)